# С Visual Studio2015 не могу подключиться к БД MySql на Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure, azure-websites, azure-storage

С Visual Studio2015 не могу подключиться к БД MySql на Azure. C MySql Workbench
получилось подключиться. К VS установил еще MySql for Vs 2.0.4 и MySqk connector .net 6.8.8. Azure SDK тоже есть версии 2.9.6.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте такой формат в секции `username` `<имяпользователя@имяхоста>` при подключении.
Прочитайте [документацию.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-portal#get-connection-information)

[Такой же вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035710/connection-to-azure-mysql-server-fails-due-to-incorrect-connection-string)

Comment: Использую и получаю ошибку.